# Extraneous Solutions

Tags: inequality

How would I solve the following inequality algebraically? I can see the solution graphically, but I'm wondering if someone can describe the extraneous solution part algebraically.

$x-7 < \sqrt{x}+3$

Comment: This is another one of those cases where $\sqrt{x}$ implies a non-negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt{x}$.  Then we have $$t^2-7<t+3\implies t^2-t-10<0, t\geq0$$

Solving, we get
\begin{align}
t^2-t-10&<0\\
\left(t-\frac12\right)^2-\frac{41}4&<0\\
\left(t-\frac12\right)^2&<\frac{41}4\\
\left|t-\frac12\right|&<\frac{\sqrt{41}}2\\
-\frac{\sqrt{41}}2<t-\frac12&<\frac{\sqrt{41}}2\\
\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{41}}2<t&<\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{41}}2\\
\end{align}

Substituting, we get $$\frac12-\frac{\sqrt{41}}2<\sqrt{x}<\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{41}}2\implies0\leq x<\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{41}}{2}\right)^2$$
and we get $\boxed{x\in\left[0,\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{41}}{2}\right)^2\right)}$.

Comment: The right limit of the interval in the final answer should be squared